# Toggle <select> tag with chrome DevTools

Tags: html, select, menu, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to keep open a  menu with Chrome DevTools?

Select open:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need this? You need this to check the hover color right? ;) Otherwise you just can select within your option list the select values

Comment: As Konrad Dzwinel answered, is just for comfortably styling options

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These selects are native OS components, there seems to be no way to control them from DevTools.

What you can do is add `multiple` attribute to your select (right click on the node and choose "Add attribute"). This will allow you to comfortably style `option` elements.

[image: select with <code>multiple</code> attribute]

Comment: Sadly this changes the select to expand within its location and does not create a drop-down overlay any more.

Comment: @Qwerty we add `multiple` here so we can comfortably style options of the select using DevTools. Once we are happy with the styling we move it to a CSS file, but we don't keep the `multiple` in our HTML.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that this expanded select looks differently than the drop-down overlay. Moreover my parent container does not allow to display more rows at once. BTW, why not simply use `size=4` instead of `multiple`?

Comment: @Qwerty ah I see, yeah it might look a bit differently, good input. `size=4` and `multiple` seem to be interchangeable in this case, what's the benefit of using `size=4`?

Comment: With size one can specify how many rows to have visible instead of "just enabling multiple" - for example when scrollbar is present. 4 was just a dice throw.